# How to find Windows 7 File Transfer History?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, usb-flash-drive

Is it possible to find out which files are transferred to an external usb flash drive in certain period of time?

To be more clear. If I/someone have a flash drive and take some data from me. How do I know which files are copied? Finding out file copy hostory could be also a work around.

Comment: +1: By the way, interesting and useful question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to monitor and report file copy activities in windows XP?](http://superuser.com/questions/103314/how-to-monitor-and-report-file-copy-activities-in-windows-xp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only kind of trace available on Windows is the Windows Event, which could be accessed from the [Windows Event Viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer), as shown below:

[image]

Unfortunately, I couldn't find (I suspect that anyone would) any specific event related with your problem (unauthorized file copies to flash drives).

I am almost sure that you will not be able to find if someone already did an unauthorized file copy from your system, but I could list two applications that would help to find if someone try the same thing in future:

- [Diskmon:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896646.aspx)

> DiskMon is an application that logs and displays all hard disk
>   activity on a Windows system. You can also minimize DiskMon to your
>   system tray where it acts as a disk light, presenting a green icon
>   when there is disk-read activity and a red icon when there is
>   disk-write activity.

- [Capture Bat:](http://www.honeynet.org/project/CaptureBAT)

> This is a behavioral analysis tool of applications for the Win32
>   operating system family. Capture BAT is able to monitor the state of a
>   system during the execution of applications and processing of
>   documents, which provides an analyst with insights on how the software
>   operates even if no source code is available. Capture BAT monitors
>   state changes on a low kernel level and can easily be used across
>   various Win32 operating system versions and configurations. CaptureBAT
>   is developed and maintained by Christian Seifert of the NZ Chapter.

Additionally, I would recommend you to use some kind of cryptography on your disk to protect your files from this kind of problem. Take a look on [Truecrypt software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt).

Hope this information helps you some way.