# Batch or VBS to log transfer file type & paths from file share

Tags: windows-7, logging, file-transfer

Would anyone know how to record/write a log based on what the user has transferred from a file share?. I know I could use Wireshark, but all I need to do is write a line to the log everytime the user(me) transfer . Both computers are running Windows 7.

Comment: Forgot to mention. I am trying to log path/file of dragging share file   and dropping to local computer being used for script.(I realize I could as well use robocopy to copy and log, but I don't want to )

Comment: Keep in mind, we're not a script writing service.  We can offer you suggestions on what to script, and help if you get stuck in specific spots while writing your script, but we won't just crank out a script on request. ;)

Comment: All I want is suggestions.

Comment: I figured it out. http://superuser.com/questions/425625/how-to-find-windows-7-file-transfer-history . Please close

Comment: If you'd like, you should be able to close your own question by clicking the "close" link directly under it (you may have to wait a bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can probably detect is if the file was Read (there's no way to tell if it was Read to look at, or Read to transfer to another folder, or PC, etc.).

First ensure you [turn on Windows' Folder Auditing](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/123362-audit-log-access-shared-folders.html), setup the folders and users (and/or groups) you want to audit.

Then you'll need to monitor the Security Event Logs for event ID 4656 (open object), and trigger and alert (or alike) when Access Request Information/Accesses section contains ReadData.  I believe this can be done via the Task Scheduler.