# How to know if someone copied files from my laptop?

Tags: windows-8

I went out for a coffee break (15 minutes) early this morning, and I forgot that I had left my laptop on my workstation table open.

I just want to find out whether someone has copied files from my laptop. Could anyone tell me where to look for traces, how to find it out?

I just saw my workmate using it when I got back, browsing his own Facebook profile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find Windows 7 File Transfer History?](http://superuser.com/questions/425625/how-to-find-windows-7-file-transfer-history), [How to monitor and report file copy activities in windows XP?](http://superuser.com/questions/103314/how-to-monitor-and-report-file-copy-activities-in-windows-xp)

Answer (score -2):

Open the *Run* dialog box by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and type in `recent`.

It *might* show there.

Comment: That will show what was recently opened/accessed, but not what was copied.

Comment: @ Paul OConnor: Well, this guy that's using my laptop when I got back knows a lot about computers. So if he indeed really copied files from my laptop, I'm quite sure he knows the way to remove/hide/erase traces. So how/what are my chances of finding it out?

Comment: very slim. theres no logging, and unless the file is written to, there should be no NTFS information on it either. NTFS no longer update the Last Accessed date unless HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate is set to true.