# How to know the file history that has been transferred from pc to usb device or vice versa?

Tags: windows, usb, powershell

When I want to know that if any usb device that has been plugged in a pc recently, I write this command in Windows Powershell.

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR\*\* | Select FriendlyName
```

This command shows the list of USB devices that have been recently connected to the computer. But my question is if I want to know that which files have been transferred from my pc to these usb devices or vice versa, what will be the command for Windows Powershell? And if it is not possible using Windows Powershell, what will be the exact solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find Windows 7 File Transfer History?](http://superuser.com/questions/425625/how-to-find-windows-7-file-transfer-history), also see: [How can I monitor and report file copy activities in Windows XP?](http://superuser.com/questions/103314/how-can-i-monitor-and-report-file-copy-activities-in-windows-xp)

Comment: Short version: There's no auditing log if you don't set one up ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

NirSoft has a number of file monitoring tools, such as *Folder Changes View*, http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_changes_view.html . as mentioned by Techie007, though, you'd need to start it before files transfer starts.